# Filtering rows in a table union mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Hello I am a having a very hard time in in this bad database structure, and I need help in filtering rows in a table union is it possible?

What's happening is that I am trying to select `pre1, pre2, pre3, pre4, pre5` in the table where the value is not null so all the rows appear but when I am trying to filter out the rows where `trno = <value>` I get an error because I do not know how to do this. Can you help me?

The code I am working on is this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT pre1 AS col FROM ccsubject
UNION
SELECT pre2 AS col FROM ccsubject
UNION
SELECT pre3 AS col FROM ccsubject
UNION
SELECT pre4 As col FROM ccsubject
UNION
SELECT pre5 AS col FROM ccsubject
) T1
WHERE col IS NOT NULL
```

I also tried this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT pre1 AS col FROM ccsubject
UNION
SELECT pre2 AS col FROM ccsubject
UNION
SELECT pre3 AS col FROM ccsubject
UNION
SELECT pre4 As col FROM ccsubject
UNION
SELECT pre5 AS col FROM ccsubject
UNION 
SELECT trno AS tr FROM ccsubject
) T1
WHERE col IS NOT NULL AND tr = 29005
```

Here's my table structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT pre1 AS col FROM ccsubject WHERE trno = 29005 AND pre1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT pre2 AS col FROM ccsubject WHERE trno = 29005 AND pre2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT pre3 AS col FROM ccsubject WHERE trno = 29005 AND pre3 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT pre4 As col FROM ccsubject WHERE trno = 29005 AND pre4 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT pre5 AS col FROM ccsubject WHERE trno = 29005 AND pre5 IS NOT NULL
) T1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the `tr` field too.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT pre1 AS col, trno AS tr FROM ccsubject
    UNION
    SELECT pre2 AS col, trno AS tr FROM ccsubject
    UNION
    SELECT pre3 AS col, trno AS tr FROM ccsubject
    UNION
    SELECT pre4 As col, trno AS tr FROM ccsubject
    UNION
    SELECT pre5 AS col, trno AS tr FROM ccsubject
) t
WHERE t.col IS NOT NULL AND
      t.tr = 29005
```

Comment: there isn't any tr column he is joining with alias of last union

Comment: Ohh. I didn't notice the last select statement. I thought all are same. @Suraz

Comment: Correct the where clause according to the selected columns, yeah its fine now

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen. Meanwhile I was editing. Thanks for your effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

- I'm not sure why you're using select * if you just want pre1, pre2,pre3, pre4, pre5.
- Also why do you want all pre columns named as `col`

`SELECT pre1, pre2, pre3, pre4, pre5
FROM ccsubject
where col is not NULL`

Comment: I only wanted to select the columns that isn't null in those 5 columns.